# A variational characterization of diameter

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, convex-geometry, variational-analysis

We can easily show that for every non-empty set $A$ in a normed space $X$,

$ \text{diam}(A) = 2\inf_{x \in X} \sup_{a \in A} \|a-x\|.$

This does not necessarily hold in the case of metric spaces.
This variational characterization of diameter is used in a part of Alexei Kulik's book "Ergodic behavior of Markov processes" in the case of $X = \mathbb R$ equipped with the Euclidean norm.
Are there any known name of this equality?